# if MySql row(field) has any text output

Tags: php, mysql

I am lost on what to put in the first line of my code here. If i have any form of text in my field i want it to output `<p> say hi! </p>` What would i put in my first line of code to make that true? If there is text this will be true if there is no text it will be ignored.

```
<?php if ($row['userid'] == What do i put here? ): ?>
 <p> say hi! </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know how to do it with number values but not text. So im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
<?php if ($row['userid'] != "" ): ?>
 <p> say hi! </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thats it? So basically like C++? As long as its not nothing?

Comment: yeah, if you just want to show "Say hi!" when it is not empty (when $row['userid'] has something) then that is one way to go.. there is other function to check if the variable is empty.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
<?php if ($row['userid']): ?>
 <p> say hi! </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As aljx0409 answered, you could try this too

```
<?php if (isset($row['userid']) && $row['userid'] != ""): ?>
 <p> say hi! </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `empty()`:

```
<?php if (!empty($row['userid'])): ?>
 <p> say hi! </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (strlen($row['userid']) > 0 ): ?>
 <p> say hi! </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

check this also :)